How to fix multi-input errors in Nextflow
I am doing multi-strain analysis in Nextflow, and I'm facing consistent errors when passing multiple outputs from one process to the next process. The errors I've encountered include 'Gstring', 'path value null', '2 inputs specified but 1 input defined', and so on. Is anyone available to help me?
The code is:
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.ref = ''    
params.reads = []

def getFastqList() {
    def input = System.console().readLine('Enter fastq filenames separated by spaces: ')
    def inputList = input.split(' ') as List
    def fullPathList = inputList.collect { it.trim() }
    return fullPathList
}

process indexReference {

    tag "BWA-INDEX:${params.ref}"

    input:
        path params.ref

    publishDir './indexed_ref/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        path "${params.ref}.bwt", emit: indexed_ref

    script:
        """
        bwa index ${params.ref}
        """
}

process trimReads {

    tag "FASTP:${sampleid}"

    input:
        tuple val(sampleid), path(reads)

    publishDir './trimtry/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        path "${sampleid}_trimmed.fastq.gz", emit: trimmed_reads

    script:
        """
        fastp -i ${reads} -o ${sampleid}_trimmed.fastq.gz
        """
}

process alignReads {

    tag "BWA:${sampleid}"

    input:
        tuple val(sampleid), path(trimmed_reads), path(indexed_ref)

    publishDir './aligntry/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        path "${sampleid}.sorted.bam", emit: aligned_bam

    script:
        """
        bwa mem ${params.ref} ${trimmed_reads} | samtools view -Sb - | samtools sort -o ${sampleid}.sorted.bam
        """
}

workflow {
    def reads = getFastqList()

    if (params.ref && reads) {
        println "Reference genome: ${params.ref}"
        println "Input reads: ${reads}"
        
        // Index the reference genome
        def indexed_ref = indexReference(params.ref)

        channel
            .from(reads) \
            .map { file -> tuple(new File(file).getName().split('\\.')[0], file) } \
            | trimReads
            | set { trim }
        
        trim
            .trimmed_reads
            | map { trimmed -> tuple(trimmed[0], trimmed[1], indexed_ref) } \
            | alignReads
            | set { aligned }
        
        aligned
            .aligned_bam
            | map { bam -> tuple('aligned_bam', bam.toString()) } \
            | set { final_bam }
            view()
    } else {
        error "Please provide valid paths for the reference genome and input reads."
    }
}

The error is:
(base) virudhagiri@virudhagiri-HP-Laptop-15s-eq2xxx:~/Desktop/ngs$ nextflow run try6.nf --ref /home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/sequence.fasta

N E X T F L O W   ~   version 24.04.4

Launching `try6.nf` [dreamy_knuth] DSL2 - revision: 5cc8b03515

Enter fastq filenames separated by spaces: ERR227102.fastq SRR30335767.fastq
Reference genome: /home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/sequence.fasta
Input reads: [/home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/ERR227102.fastq, /home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/SRR30335767.fastq]
executor > local (3)
[b4/6f8da3] process > indexReference (IndexReference) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[47/e708f4] process > trimReads (FASTP: ERR227102)    [100%] 2 of 2 ✓
[-        ] process > alignReads                      -
[-        ] process > sortBam                         -
[-        ] process > markDuplicates                  -
[-        ] process > variantCalling                  -
[-        ] process > annotation                      -
[-        ] process > SNPFiltering                    -
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'alignReads (1)'
Caused by:
  Trying to evaluate a GString containing a Closure taking 2 parameters

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details


The line that causes the problem is the map after trimmed_reads:
trim
    .trimmed_reads
    | map { trimmed -> tuple(trimmed[0], trimmed[1], indexed_ref) } \

Because indexed_ref is a channel. To combine channels (with a cross product),
you can use the channel operator combine or modify the process input with the each keyword.
So the correct line would be:
trim
    | combine (indexed_ref)

(No need for using a named output here).
Additionally, your trimReads process forgot to output the value sampleid, so you should fix it:
process trimReads {

    tag "FASTP:${sampleid}"

    input:
        tuple val(sampleid), path(reads)

    publishDir './trimtry/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        tuple val(sampleid), path("${sampleid}_trimmed.fastq.gz")  # Changed line.

    script:
        """
        fastp -i ${reads} -o ${sampleid}_trimmed.fastq.gz
        """
}

Also, in your process indexReference, you should not use:
input:
path params.ref

but
input:
path ref

i.e. use the "ref" variable name. The same goes for other places where you use params.ref.

@VirudhagiriE You can ask another question with detailed input/output. Also have a look at the Nextflow community forum.
